# creating popup window with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, popup, alert, popupwindow

I want to use some popup/alert window that contains a URL.

Something like:

```
alert(localhost:2828\index.html);
```

I am sure I have seen it before.
If there is some bootstrap, then it will be even better.

Comment: Would `alert("localhost:2828\\index.html");` suffice  ?

Comment: Are you trying to open a new window?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to display a website as a pop-up, you should try this [library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/website-popup).

Comment: that is exactly what I want, but it works only in IOS

Comment: No, you have to use javascript. So most probably, you can use it on any browser, irrespective of the operating system.